# spacy matcher on_match called twice

Tags: python-3.x, spacy

my question is i took the code from spacy documentation which is

```
def on_match(matcher, doc, id, matches):
    print("Matched!", matches)

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
patterns = [
    [{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}],
    [{"ORTH": "Google"}, {"ORTH": "Maps"}],
]
matcher.add("TEST_PATTERNS", patterns, on_match=on_match)
doc = nlp("HELLO WORLD on Google Maps.")
matches = matcher(doc)
```

How can i merge the these patterns to match only something like "HELLO WORLD ... Google Maps". Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If you add

```py
for match_id, start, end in matches:
    print(doc[start:end].text)
```

The output will be

```
HELLO WORLD
Google Maps
```

Thus, you have two matches and they occur because

- `[{"LOWER": "hello"}, {"LOWER": "world"}]` - a pattern that returns two consecutive tokens whose lowercased value is `hello` and `world` (so, it finds `HELLO WORLD` alright)
- `[{"ORTH": "Google"}, {"ORTH": "Maps"}]` - a pattern that returns two consecutive tokens whose value is exactly `Google` and `Maps` (so, it finds `Google Maps` alright).